# How do I inject a service into a C# Dotnet Core ILogger?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ilogger

I've followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider to create a custom logger. I want this custom logger to then have messages processed by a service - which I'd provide as a service in the DI container. For example, send the log messages to clients of a SignalR hub.

However, that's not possible as the ILogger initialisation happens before the Startup.cs code. Is there any recommended way of passing messages from an ILogger to another service? I suppose that registering this before the ConfigureLogging would work, but I'd like to know if there's any obvious good alternatives first.

Comment: I think you should redesign your logging logic, the logger should not depend on some service of your own. You can such as create your logging service which consumes the logger (basically like a wrapper exposing the same interface as the logger). It allows you to intercept the calls right in your logging service. This however requires you to use your logging service instead of ILogger directly. This can work for your code but not possible for framework & third-party code which depends on ILogger directly.

Comment: I also think it makes sense to use a custom service for these sort of non-trivial scenarios. The built-in architectural elements often prove to be quite inflexible, and you can end up banging your head against the proverbial wall quite fast. With a custom service that wraps the logger you have full flexibility, and it's easy to implement. IMyLogger FTW. ;)

Comment: Hey, I'll try and publish some code to illustrate this. I think in the end I will indeed need to redesign the system. The problem is that I want this to be a pluggable library that others can use (like the Seq Serilog Appender/Seq ILogger appender). So I can't really use a IMyLogger in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
Try to follow this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Please give more details about your goal , but as I understood if you register your ilogger in the startup you can call it whenever you want in your sending messages service

Comment: I'm afraid I'm trying to do the opposite - I don't want services to use a logger, I want the logger to use services. But I don't think this is possible without some painful additions.